# regex to find script and stylesheet tags

Tags: regex

I am trying to get all script tags and link tags for stylesheets only.
Right now I have this:

```
var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
```

Text:

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/roboto-v27-latin/roboto-v27-latin-700.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="css/site.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" media="screen">
<script src="plugins/glider-js/glider.min.js"></script>
```

It matches the js file.
But how to get the  tag for site.css too?
This is what I am trying to do:

```
var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>|<link rel="stylesheet">/gm;
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be using regex to parse HTML. Use DOMParser instead of you need to search for elements in a string that contains HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the = + stylesheet you should find all your links with few false positives. We make sure that we don't include any `</script>`tag before the last one.
If there are nested script tags this will return the inner pair.
I'm assuming that all of your tags are lower case : `<script>` and not `<SCRIPT>`. We could write the regex to capture both if there is a risk of missing valid links.

```
<script((?!(<(\/)script))[\s\S])*\=['\"]?(stylesheet)['\"]?((?!(<(\/)script))[\s\S])*<\/script>
```